# Multiple registration of a service with different instance scopes in Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm working with a legacy codebase which uses Autofac and registers a lot of (if not all) of dependencies as PerRequest.

We're developing new pieces of functionality and would like for new services to have their dependencies resolved individually for each service, not per request. The initial service is obtained by Service Locator via Resolve.

What's the optimal way to achieve this using Autofac?

I believe Keyed Services might be of assistance here. Here's an example of the configuration:

```
builder.RegisterType<Impl>().As<IDependency>().InstancePerLifetimeScope(); 
builder.RegisterType<Impl>().As<IDependency>().InstancePerDependency().Keyed<IDependency>("shinyNewService");       

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(newServiceAssembly).AsClosedTypesOf(newServiceInterface).WithParameter
                    (
                        new ResolvedParameter
                        (
                            (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IDependency),
                            (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed<IDependency>("shinyNewService")
                        )
                    );
```

It seems to work in my case, but 
we'd also like to get a new instance of ShinyNewService each time Resolve is called, so I think it makes sense to configure it to be `InstancePerDependency` as well.

Does anyone have any advice regarding this approach? I was also considering tagged lifetime scopes, but didn't manage to come up with a complete solution. Any input is welcome, thanks.

Comment: Solutions can be found be it would be counter-intuitive and difficult to maintain. It looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Could you explain more why do you need this behavior ?

Comment: Of course. The actual dependency is a unit of work (dbContext from EF) and some business processes are too complex to be treated as 'web request equals transaction'. They have separate transactions initiated, and sometimes we'd like to write something in a nested transaction without affecting the outer one.

Comment: what about using `InstancePerLifetimeScope` for your unit of work and using a new lifetimescope for the other business process ? This is the common approach for such a situation

Comment: I gave it a try yesterday but I didn't come up with a complete solution. However, right now I guess we could get rid of PerRequest configuration at all and simply use PerLifetimeScope. In cases with usual requests the lifetime scope will be a web request one, which Autofac creates automatically, and for our special cases we would create additional nested scopes. Looks pretty decent on paper, I'll try it tomorrow.